# How to change variable name inside loop dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have foreach loop to listView control, I want to create objects for every listView content, so i want to change the name of the object incrementally by foreach loop

```
foreach (var item in listViewStates.Items)
            {
               State s = new State 
               {
                   ID = MaxStateID,
                   Name = listViewStates.Items[0].Text,
                   WorkflowID = MaxWFID,
                   DueDate = Convert.ToInt32(listViewStates.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text),
                   Priority = Convert.ToInt32(listViewStates.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text),
                   RoleID = Convert.ToInt32(listViewStates.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text),
                   Status =Convert.ToInt32(listViewStates.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text)
               };
               i++;
            }
```

the variable is s from the State Class

Comment: Where is i defined and where is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have the wrong approach. What you need to do with your state object is add it to a collection, and work it from there. It's much easier to track this way.

Example with a local list for use after the loop, in the function:

```
public void MyFunction()
{
    List<State> states = new List<State>();

    foreach (var item in listViewStates.Items)
    {
        State s = new State
        {
            //Set state properties
        };
        states.Add(s);
    }
    //Use your states here, address with brackets
    //states[0].ID ...
}
```

Example with a class-level list for later use outside the function:

```
List<State> _states;

public void MyFunction()
{
    _states = new List<State>();
    foreach (var item in listViewStates.Items)
    {
        State s = new State
        {
            //Set state properties
        };
        _states.Add(s);
    }
    //Now, after calling the function, your states remain
    //You can address them the same way as above, with brackets
    //_states[0].ID ...
}
```

Comment: As you see, I declared S from State, but I want to use i variable in naming the object from State to use the objects later....

Comment: That can't be done. Put it in a collection to use it later. I'll give you an example.